# Lock not working properly in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, locking

I put lock on a few lines which are supposed to get cookie files and read them, but I see sometimes an error saying file already in use! So not sure whats going wrong...

Code:

```
private Object cookieLock = new Object();

main{
    for (int j = 0; j < maxThreads; j++)
        {
            //   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startPosting2(worker)));
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => postingFunction2());
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

public void postFunction2()
{
 string tmpUsername = string.Empty;
 string[] array2 = null;
   try
    {
      lock (cookieLock)
       {
          array2 = File.ReadAllLines(tmpUsername + ".txt");
       }
    }
   catch(Exception ex)
    {
      TextWriter sUrl = new StreamWriter("readingSameCookieFile.txt", true);
      sUrl.WriteLine(exp.ToString());
      sUrl.Close();
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? These lines are executed by 20-100 threads simultaneously, I do not see it much but I do see it some time, so wondering why!

TXT FILE ERROR:

> `System.IO.IOException`: The process cannot access the file `'C:\Users\Administrator\My Projects\Bot Files\2 Message Poster Bot\MessagePoster - NoLog - Copy\cookies\LaureneZimmerebner57936.txt'` because it is being used by another process.

Comment: Maybe the error is inside the exception block?  There's no lock there.

Comment: you are not displaying the whole code, but i can feel that your design is not good.

Comment: What file is in use? I bet it is the `readingSameCookieFile.txt`

Comment: @Erno good point i did not check that , will look now!

Comment: @Erno the error is not with the exception file its one of the cookies file , i checked...

Comment: Are you accessing that file anywhere else? Is the file still open after debugging?

Comment: @Erno Nope these are closed and hte code runs good , as i said it happens maybe only for 100 -300 rows in a bunch of 10000 rows but still why does it.

Comment: Each instance of your class gets its own `cookieLock`, so are you perhaps instantiating your class multiple times?

Comment: Are you sure your app is the only program that accesses the file. if there are others this exception is normal

Comment: Is the `tmpUsername` shared across threads or is it a local variable?

Comment: `array2` is not a member in your class instead of being a scope variable, right?

Comment: Please post any other code that accesse files, and tell us what exact line the exception occur on. You have to keep in mind in order to use `lock` you have to lock the same instance of the object.

Comment: Where is `tmpUsername` introduced in the code?

Comment: i have update question to make it more sensible....

Comment: If what hvd is saying is true, then you might be able to solve this problem simply by defining `cookieLock` as static: `private static Object cookieLock = new Object();`.

Comment: Couple of remarks besides the lock: creating so 20-100 actual threads is unlikely to speed things up because you probably won;t have that many cores. Then this will force a lot of context switching for these threads, slowing your app down. You can look into Tasks from the Task Parallel Library to have .Net find the optimal number of threads for your box. Another usual bottleneck is the disk, reading in parallel will probably lead to contention on the disk(although cookies are so small this may be less of an issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to overcome the problem you are having and are sure it's not beeing written then you can use this function instead of `File.ReadAllLines`. The key is it the share options it gives `FileShare.ReadWrite`.

```
private static string[] ReadAllLines(string fileName)
{
  using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open,
                                           FileAccess.Read,
                                           FileShare.ReadWrite))
  {
    var reader = new StreamReader(fs);
    //read all at once and split, or can read line by line into a list if you prefer
    var allLines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
                                            StringSplitOptions.None);
    return allLines;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was something i was looking for.....Will implement it now and seee.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to read file only once and share `array2` among the 20-100 thread, because reading it multiple times will cause performance degradations. Also in multithreading environment it is recommended to keep all I/O operations in single thread.

Sharing array2 won't require locks if it will be only read by all threads.

```
Debug.Write(file name);// to make sure each thread opens different file.
```

Comment: Then you don't need a lock but the maximum number of files that can be opened at the same time is 20 files per application. This is windows limitation.

Comment: @So i am maybe running 50 threads,but the exception clearly say , the file is in use, than any limit error!

Comment: You need to make sure each thread is opening different file then.

Comment: I got your point, but why doe the exception say file already in use? than any limit !like limit exceeded etc..

Comment: That depends on the rows, each row has a username and password, so 30 threads running 20 maybe same username and password and the other 10 are different so 20 should go one by one to read the same cookie file and get the info in it, hope this helped...

Comment: There should be a semaphore and all threads wait on that semaphore to get the next piece of work they should work on. Then only on thread the main one will read all cookies and push them in queue and signal the semaphore. That is how I see you app should be.

Comment: At the end the main thread will wait for all threads to finish.

Comment: There is much going on . but i posted a sample example here.....just wanted to know the issue with the lock

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read cookies; may be the browser or some other application outside your code is accessing/writing to the cookie file, hence the exception.

you have not posted the entire code, just make sure the lock object is not instantiated multiple times or make it static to be sure.
Also try adding Thread.Sleep(0) after reading; see if that helps.

If you writing the contents of array2 to another file, make sure that is disposed/closed properly after writing.

tryin putting the entire method inside the lock block

```
public void postFunction2() 
{ 
 lock (cookieLock) 
 { 
 string tmpUsername = string.Empty; 
 string[] array2 = null; 
   try 
    { 
          array2 = File.ReadAllLines(tmpUsername + ".txt"); 
    } 
   catch(Exception ex) 
    { 
      TextWriter sUrl = new StreamWriter("readingSameCookieFile.txt", true); 
      sUrl.WriteLine(exp.ToString()); 
      sUrl.Close(); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing other than this write the file :) , there are made by this code and then used by it, first a function runs and logins to accounts and save cookies, than this function is executed....